# Pydantic model_validate with generic abstract classes

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I have a generic response class

```
RESP = TypeVar("RESP", bound=BaseModel)

class TestResponse(BaseModel, Generic[RESP]):
    status: str
    data: RESP
```

And an example model class

```
class Example(BaseModel):
    description: str


ExampleResponse = RootModel[list[Example]]
```

I have an abstract method and an implementation that returns response_model

```
# file 1
@abstractmethod
def response_model(self) -> Type[RESP]:
    pass

# file 2 - implementation
def response_model(self) -> Type[ExampleResponse]:
    return ExampleResponse
```

And am trying to validate the model in the abstract class using

```
response = {"status": "success", "data": [{"description": "ok"}]}
resp_model = self.response_model()
return TestResponse[resp_model].model_validate(response)
```

the code seems to work (no exceptions thrown and if I change spelling of "description" to "descriptions" in response.data[0] an exception will be thrown as expected). However, MyPy shows an error

> Mypy: The type "Type[ConsumerResponse[Any]]" is not generic and not
> indexable [misc]

and

> Mypy: Type expected within [...] [misc]

What is the cause of that and how to fix it?